# How can I update data from class Objects when I send them to a new Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities (ActivityA and ActivityB)
In ActivityA i'm creating a new Object Game which has an ArrayList inside
Game game = new Game();

I start ActivityB

```
public void startActivityB(View view){

    Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
    i.putExtra("Game", game);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

In activity B I get the object, access to they ArrayList and delete some elements. (I check the ArrayList before and after deleting, and they were successfully deleted)
The problem is that when i finish the ActivityB, and start it again, the deleted elements  are still on the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

You should start activity B with `startActivityForResult`, and pass back to ActiviyA the modified ArrayList through `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are editing two different instances of a duplicated object. Consider making it static in Activity A and accessing it directly in Activity B.

OR

Consider an MVC structure for your app. You should really not be passing multiple versions of large amount of data across activities. Standardize the way in which you access and modify the data.